CarouselSlider Page filling
I'm designing a book mockup using CrouselSlider in my Flutter app. I need to convert each word of the text I have into a widget and display it on the screen with the Wrap widget. Once the current page in the CarouselSlider is full, I have to continue from the next page. I don't know how I can do this.
 for (int i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
      GlobalKey anahtar = GlobalKey();
      harfler.add(
        Text(
            texts[i],
            key: anahtar,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35),
          ),
      );
    }

The piece of code I gave above is purely representative. much more complex widgets will be included in the loop.
The Widget list I created above will later be used to populate the CarouselSlider pages.
for (int i = 0; i < harfler.length; i++) {
      print(i);
      sayfaHarfleri.add(harfler[i]);

      sayfa = Container(
        width: pageWidth,
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          maxHeight: pageHeight,
          minHeight: pageHeight - 10,
        ),
        child: Wrap(
          children: sayfaHarfleri,
        ),
      );
      if (sayfa.constraints?.maxHeight < sayfa.size!.height) {
        debugPrint("Sayfa maxHeight'i aşıldı. İndex: $i");
        pages.add(sayfa);
        sayfaHarfleri = [];
      }
      
    }

In the code above, I tried to create a new page when the page was full, but I did not get any results.
page.size!.height I cannot access the size of the current page element
I came here to get help because I couldn't create an algorithm that fills the screen completely and starts filling the new page.
